# How to add supporting edges for subdiv to this shape?

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface

How do I add supporting edge loops for the purposes of subdiv on this shape?
[image]

[image]

In most places it was fairly easy to add supporting edges of a consistent width (0.002 units). The only place I am really struggling is here, where that large n-gon gets pinched to a sliver where it intersects the cylinder.

Is this problem better solved with *more* or *fewer* segments on the cylinder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Delete big n-gon face
- Select cylinder loop with Shift+Alt (it will select just needed half)
- Extrude and Scale a bit
- on side add loop with Ctrl+R and slide (for each of three)
- Merge vertices on edge

[image]

[image]
(from other side just Merge one vertex)

[image]

Probably would be better to merge the smallest triangle face, if possible ... But seems to be serving well as it is.

*Note: As you can see there is one vertex in curvature that didnt moved ... I can't figure out why and how it can be locked on X axis :) Hm*

You can also select big ngon face and use **Inset** (I) technique, but you would have to clean up a mess in corners anyway :) With Inset I didnt get the single vertex issue, way more strange ... Hm

Answer (score 1):

This topology seems to work fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several options here: you could fix up the geometry (maybe try the grid fill tool) to achieve proper edge flow, or inset the big n-gon, or even crease it.